# Swift's enum with one case causes BAD_ACCESS at runtime

Tags: xcode, swift, enums, swift2, xcode7.3

I've found strange bug in Swift 2.2 on Xcode 7.3 (or it's not a bug but I'm doing something wrong).

I've got enum with one case and class that takes this enum as an initializer's parameter

```
enum OneCaseEnum {
    case X
}

class OneEnumWrapper {
    var myVar: OneCaseEnum

    init(v: OneCaseEnum)
    {
        self.myVar = v
    }
}
```

Now if I run this code in real app i.e. somewhere in AppDelegate:

```
let e = OneCaseEnum.X
print(e)
let x = OneEnumWrapper(v: e)
print(x)
```

I got BAD_ACEESS at runtime in 3rd line.

- It crashes in Xcode 7.3 (on previous versions works OK).
- In playground works OK.
- If I add another enum case works OK
- If I mark myVar as unwrapped optional works OK

Am I doing something wrong or is it Swift/Xcode/compiler/something else bug?

Comment: @Grimxn that's what I said above - crashes only in real app, in playground it's OK

Comment: That looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely a bug with the compiler.  Oddly enough, adding a second `case` to your `enum` works perfectly:

```
enum OneCaseEnum {
    case X
    case Y
}

class OneEnumWrapper {
    var myVar: OneCaseEnum

    init(v: OneCaseEnum)
    {
        self.myVar = v
    }
}

let e = OneCaseEnum.X
print(e)
let x = OneEnumWrapper(v: e) // no crash
print(x)
```

You can use this as a workaround until this crash is identified and fixed.

[rdar://25314388](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5037019633811456)

[SR-1035](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1035)

[Sample project](https://github.com/JALsnipe/SwiftOneCaseEnumCrash)

Comment: That's what i did. Sadly it's second compiler bug in this month that I've found...

Comment: @Kubba looks like the bug was prioritized as medium and pulled into "Open" so hopefully we'll get a response soon.